# how to send the postno(post number ID) which was fetched from database to another component?

Tags: node.js, angular

code:

```
<div class="news" *ngFor="let post of list">
   <mat-accordion class="accordion">
      <mat-expansion-panel>
         <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title >{{post.title}}</mat-panel-title>
            <div class="w3-right">
                <mat-panel-title >{{post.date}}</mat-panel-title>
            </div>
         </mat-expansion-panel-header>
         {{post.description}}
         <app-gallery [postno]={{post.pNo}}></app-gallery>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
   </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

but the output is :

> Parser Error: Unexpected token `{`, expected identifier, keyword, or
>   string at column 2 in `[{{post.pNo}}]` in
>   `ng:///AppModule/ForumComponent.html@44:27` ("

Comment: how does your `post` data look in component? You can post that so that we can know it's structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This should work provided you have pNo inside post**

```
   <div class="news" *ngFor="let post of list">
      <mat-accordion class="accordion">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title >{{post.title}}</mat-panel-title>
            <div class="w3-right">
            <mat-panel-title >{{post.date}}</mat-panel-title>
          </div>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          {{post.description}}
          <app-gallery [postno]="post?.pNo"></app-gallery>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `input` to app-gallery into quotes:

```
 <app-gallery [postno]="post?.pNo"></app-gallery>
```

Assuming you have the `post` data object available in the component where it's used and it has a property `pNo`. If `pNo` is not present on `post` object use the property that matches the ID as required.

to enable safe interpolation, you can add `?`

Comment: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{post.pNo}}] in ng:///AppModule/ForumComponent.html@44:27 ("        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
              {{post.description}}
              <app-gallery [ERROR ->][postno]="{{post.pNo}}"></app-gallery>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
          </mat-accordion>
"): ng:///AppModule/ForumComponent.html@44:27

Comment: Oh, or you can just use it without {{}}